# cannot set a variable within a wmic useraccount request

Tags: powershell, user-accounts

Folks,

I'm trying to set some attributes for a large set of user accounts on a W10 system.

To do so, I create a table of usernames with get-localgoupmember, which I parse with a foreach command.
Let's assume that I have a variable called $x

I cannot succed get this working :

wmic useraccount where "Name=$x" set passwordexpires=true

(while I have no problems with the command : wmic useraccount where "Name='JohnDoe'" set passwordexpires=true)

So it has to be a subsitution issue and a syntax problem (probably trivial and stupid but I'm stuck)

Any hint will be greatly appreciated.

TIA and warm regards

Answer (score 0):

The `''` are crucial, which you are missing with your `$x`.

Here is a short Powershell Script that will work:

```
$x = "John Doe"

wmic useraccount where "Name='$x'" set passwordexpires=true
# note these:                ^  ^
```